# [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Tags: php

I have tried the solution for this problem and 
for this

```
Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty
```

and for this also

```
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
```

Like Backslash and forward slash problem

But still facing problem
Please help me..
I am trying to change content of file on server with my file..

```
$frserver =  file_get_contents("http:\\ip is here\\cdr\\settings.txt");
```

(i have tried with single slash and forward slash also) but same issue..
AFter getting this file, i cut a character

```
$result = substr($frserver, 12, 1);
```

which returns me a integer value

Now I do same procedure with my local computer

```
$frlocal =  file_get_contents("c:\\settings.txt", "r");
$result1 = substr($frlocal, 12, 1);
```

Now comparing both characters..if same no issue if not same...write in server file with my local file content.

```
if($result == $result1){
    echo "No file to Update";
}
else{
$fh = fopen( $frserver, "w" );
fwrite( $fh, $frlocal );
    fclose( $fh );
    echo "file updated";
```

}

please have a look.

Comment: This is very confusing.  What are you trying to do?  Why are you opening a file who's name is contained in another file that you fetch from the internet?

Comment: `fopen()` is expecting `$frserver` to be a file name, not a block of data (nor empty). `fclose()` fails because `fopen()` failed. `file_get_contents()` has an "r" as the second param, which it shouldn't (appears like it used to be a `fopen()` call?).

Comment: i am having same file on both places..like settings.txt on remote server and on my computer so i am to match both of them...you told fopen() is expecting a file name but i am not downloading any file...i just read it above and gave that path..

Comment: What is in the `$frserver` variable? `fopen()` expects that it contains a file name, but it looks like it contains the contents of `http://ip is here/cdr/settings.txt`. What's in it?

Comment: @wiseguy settings.txt is a file which is situated at http://ip/cdr path...so i put that there..i have not downloaded the file so gave file path

Comment: Because of `$frserver = file_get_contents(...);`, it looks like `$frserver` contains everything that is _in_ settings.txt, not the filename of settings.txt. So `fopen()` is looking for a file called "SET VERSION=2 SET BACKUP...". Obviously, that isn't a file.

Comment: pls tell then how to give file name...file is at other location in c:\cdr\settings.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$frserver =  file_get_contents("http:\\ip is here\\cdr\\settings.txt");
```

replace all double backslashes `\\` with 1 slash `/`

```
$frserver =  file_get_contents("http://ip is here/cdr/settings.txt");
```

Web URLs are using slashes not backslashes.

Here you must provide path to file...

```
$fh = fopen( "http://ip is here/cdr/settings.txt", "w" );
```

Comment: Thanks for this help..but still I am facing fopen,fwrite and fclose warning..pls help them

Comment: [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument for fopen and Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource for fwrite and Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource for fclose

Comment: i tried your given solution also...but it shows  failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Comment: but dear..file is at other location,not on my system...i am writing that file with my local file content

Comment: You can't write file on other server with fopen fclose etc.. 
You have to create ftp connection and to upload your file..